# React align right/hide items on ANTD 4.21 Menu

Tags: css, reactjs, navigation, menuitem, ant-design-pro

Is there a way I can add different classes or an attribute to align right 2 items of this **ant design** top navigation menu? Also how can I hide an item conditionally? IE if there's an user logged in, I want to hide an item.

```
import { HomeOutlined, SettingOutlined, LoginOutlined, UserAddOutlined} from '@ant-design/icons';
import { Menu } from 'antd';
import { useState } from 'react';
const items = [
    {
        label: 'Home',
        key: 'home',
        icon: <HomeOutlined />,
    },  
    {
        label: 'Username',
        key: 'SubMenu',
        icon: <SettingOutlined />,
        children: [
            {
                type: 'group',
                children: [
                    {
                        label: 'Option 1',
                        key: 'setting:1',
                    },
                    {
                        label: 'Option 2',
                        key: 'setting:2',
                    },
                ],
            },
        ],
    },
    {
        label: 'Login',
        key: 'login',
        icon: <LoginOutlined />
    },
    {
        label: 'Register',
        key: 'register',
        icon: <UserAddOutlined />,
        

    },
];
const Header = () => {
    const [current, setCurrent] = useState('home');
    const onClick = (e) => {
        setCurrent(e.key);
    };
    return (        
        <Menu onClick={onClick} selectedKeys={[current]} mode="horizontal"  items={items} />
    );
};

export default Header;
```

I'm using ant design's top navigation menu: https://ant.design/components/menu/#API

I checked their documentation and other places but I can't seem to figure it out. I would appreciate any help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it is too late to respond :)
As far as I know, there is no "one-line" solution for this. You should make the conditions with JS using conditional JSX.
For example (in JSX, in the return expression in your React Component):

```
{checkedCondition &&

    <Menu type one .../>
}

{uncheckedCondition &&

    <Menu type two .../>

}
```